# Line jumps in text loaded in a textarea get lost when using ngModel as binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

I have the need to display a string returned by a server I have no access to in the format "line1\nline2". The thing is using ngModel to bind that string to a textarea makes it display literally `line1\nline2` instead of

```
line1
line2
```

Tried ngBind too and it didn't work either.

The textarea goes like this:

```
<textarea placeholder="some-placeholder" id="some-id" type="text" rows="4" cols="48" ng-model="backendResponse.key" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

I realize this question might have already been answered before but Google not recognizing "\n" as part as the search makes it even harder to find it so I count with you forgiving me if that was the case.

**Update:**
I got it working by running
`backendResponse.key = backendResponse.key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');`
Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I would if I could. This is work for a client.

Comment: try to create example in fiddle, no need of your complete or client code

Comment: It actually works on the fiddle. I'll try to narrow down the differences and report my findings.

Comment: Have you tried escaping your string? Seeing as line1&#13;line2 should work in a textarea.

Comment: Yes, I did @RuneVikestad. Sadly it not only fails to fix the problem but it also makes the textarea display the string as code unreadable for a human .

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom directive that replaces the newline characters with `<br />` tags.

To use it, initialize a model in your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = 'hello\nthere';
});
```

Pass in the model to the `display` directive:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <display model="model"></display>
</div>
```

**Complete Code**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('display', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch('model', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          var model = newVal.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
          element.html(model);
        }
      });
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-init="model='hello\nthere'">
    <textarea ng-model="model"></textarea>
    <br />
    <display model="model"></display>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is inside the textarea and BR won't work in there.